# ComponentOne for WinRT: Gauge Pointerlength error?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, componentone

Whenever I add a ComponentOne gauge to my page, I receive the following exception:

**WinRT information: The property 'PointerLength' was not found in type
'C1LinearGaugePointer'.**

my Xaml looks like this:

```
<c1:C1SpeedometerGauge x:Name="myGauge"
                                    Height="300" 
                                    Value="80"
                           CoverVisibility="Collapsed">
        <c1:C1GaugeRange To="40" Location="0.95" Fill="#088080" Width="0.1" Opacity="0.2" />
        <c1:C1GaugeRange From="0" To="80" Location="0.9" Fill="#088080" Width="0.05" Opacity="0.4" />
        <c1:C1GaugeRange From="0" To="100" Location="0.88" Fill="#088080" Width="0.025" Opacity="0.6" />
        <c1:C1GaugeMark Interval="20" Location="0.95"/>
        <c1:C1GaugeMark Interval="10" Location="0.95"/>
        <c1:C1GaugeMark Interval="5"  Location="0.95"/>
        <c1:C1GaugeLabel Interval="20" Alignment="In" AlignmentOffset="10" FontSize="16" />
    </c1:C1SpeedometerGauge>
```

what can be wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's known issue, it has been fixed in build 315. Take the latest build here: http://prerelease.componentone.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, downloading the latest pre-release solved the problem